# for which $a$ the integrand $\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln^3(x)}{1+x^a}dx$ converges.

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I would like to show for which $a$ the integrand $$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln^3(x)}{1+x^a}dx$$ converges.

For $a=1$ it diverges since $$\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3(x)}{x+2}dx+\int^{\infty}_1\frac{\ln^3(x)}{x+1}dx\leq \int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln^3(x)}{x+1}dx$$

and since $$\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3(x)}{x+2}dx$$ diverges, the integrand diverges.

But I am struggling to prove that it converges for all other $a$. How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: $$
\int_0^1 {\frac{{\log ^3 x}}{{x^2 }}dx}  =  - \infty , \quad
\int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\log ^3 x}}{{x + 1}}dx}  =  + \infty
$$ so it does not say much. Near $x=0$, $$
\frac{{\log ^3 x}}{{1 + x^a }} \sim \log ^3 x
$$ which is integrable on $(0,1)$, say. The convergence will depend only on what happens at infinity.

Comment: @Gary I edited it for $a=1$. Is it correct now?

Comment: Why would $$
\int_0^1 {\frac{{\log ^3 x}}{{x + 2}}dx} 
$$ be divergent? It is finite. Why did you choose that $2$? I told you that the problem is at infinity not at $0$.

Comment: @Gary well I checked and it's divergent

Comment: @Gary see picture

Comment: $$
\left| {\int_0^1 {\frac{{\log ^3 x}}{{x + 2}}dx} } \right| \le \int_0^1 {\left| {\log ^3 x} \right|dx}  = 3! = 6,
$$ see also https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28Log+x%29%5E3%2F%28x%2B2%29+from+0+to+1

Comment: @use80085 which software are you using to compute the integral?

Comment: @Algebrology this one https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-2/definite-integral-calculator/?f=ln+%5E3+%28x%29%2F%28x%2B2%29&var=&a=0&b=1

Comment: @use80085 I just proved you that it converges. Also, use Wolfram Alpha instead.

Comment: @Gary okay, will do. I'm not sure then how to prove for $a=1$ and $a>1$ then

Comment: $\int_0^1 {\frac{{\log ^3 x}}{{x + 2}}dx}=6 \text{Li}_4\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\sim -2.91429$

Comment: The main thing is that your integral converges if and only if $$
\int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\log ^3 x}}{{1 + x^a }}dx} 
$$ converges. This is because $$
\left| {\int_0^1 {\frac{{\log ^3 x}}{{1 + x^a }}dx} } \right| \le \int_0^1 {\left| {\log ^3 x} \right|dx}  = 6
$$ for $a\geq 0$. I assume you are looking at non-negative values of $a$.

Comment: @Gary but if the lower bound is $0$ then why are you taking it as $1$? sorry if I am being silly, I am not aware of calc 2 integrals. Thanks

Comment: @Gary yes, non-negative

Comment: @Algebrology Because on $(0,1)$ the integral is finite, so it is enough to look at what happens on the rest of the half-line.

Comment: @Gary Ah I see, thanks

Comment: It does not have a direct relation to the question, but it is interesting to note that the integral has a closed form (which can be obtained, for example, via contour integration):$$I(a)=-6\cos(\pi/a)\frac{(\pi/a)^4}{\sin^4(\pi/a)}\Big(1-\frac{1}{6}\sin^2(\pi/a)\Big) ,\,\, a>1$$ Quick check gives $I(a=2)=0$ and $I(a\to\infty)=-6$ - as it is clear from the initial view of the integral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the integral as follows :
$$ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\log(x))^3}{1+x^a} = \int\limits_{0}^{e} \frac{(\log(x))^3}{1+x^a} + \int\limits_{e}^{\infty} \frac{(\log(x))^3}{1+x^a}$$

The integral is said to exist when both both integrals on the right side exist. We start analysing $\int\limits_{e}^{\infty} \frac{(\log(x))^3}{1+x^a}$.
For $x \geq e$, $\log(x) \geq 1$ and so $\int\limits_{e}^{\infty} \frac{(\log(x))^3}{1+x^a} \geq \int\limits_{e}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^a}$.
This shows that the the integral diverges for $a \leq 1$.
Pick $a > 1$. Now for any $b>0$, $\frac{(\log(x))^3}{x^b}$ converges to zero as $x$ goes to $+\infty$.
Hence, after a certain large value $M_b > 0$, we'll have
$$ \int\limits_{M_b}^{\infty} \frac{(\log(x))^3}{1+x^a} < \int\limits_{M_b}^{\infty} \frac{x^b}{1+x^a}  $$
Do this procedure by chosing $b >0 $ and $a-b > 1$, then we'll have
$$\int\limits_{M_b}^{\infty} \frac{x^b}{1+x^a} = \int\limits_{M_b}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{-b}+x^{a-b}}$$
This proves the convergence of integral for any $a>1$.

For analysing $\int\limits_{0}^{e} \frac{(\log(x))^3}{1+x^a}$, make the change of variable $x = \frac{1}{t}$ and use similar analysis done above. You should get the convergence holds for all $a>0$.

Hence, the integral $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\log(x))^3}{1+x^a}$ exist for all $a>1$

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer! Could you please clarify exactly why if $\int^{\infty}_e\frac{\ln(x))^3}{1+x^a}$ diverges for $a\geq 1$ then $\int^{\infty}_1\frac{\ln(x))^3}{1+x^a}$ diverges? I understand the reasoning for the former, but not quite sure why the latter one with lower bound $1$ converges?

Comment: @use80085 the former integral converges for $a > 1$. If $a \leq 1$, then $\int\limits_{e}^{\infty} \frac{ (ln(x))^3 }{1+x^a}$ diverges. Since, you can break the later integral into two parts, one consisting of integral from 1 to $e$ , and the other from $e$ to $\infty$. Note that the function is continuous on $[1,e]$, so the convergence or divergence will depend upon the integral on $[e,\infty)$